# Undefined property of variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the proper way to make this code work?

```
$(function(){

    var base = {
            $wrapper: $('.homepage_main'),
            $main: base.$wrapper.find('#primary').find('.home_slides').closest('[data-id="Colleague"]'),
            $panel: base.$wrapper.find('#sidebar').find('.home_slides').closest('[data-id="Colleague"]'),

            Template: {
                $img: function () { return $('img'); }
            },

            Modal: {
                $modalInterrupt: $('#searching_interruption'),
                Suggestion: {
                    $self: $('#suggested_colleague'),
                    $loading: base.Modal.Suggestion.$self.find('.gif_loading'),
                    $paging: base.Modal.Suggestion.$self.find('.pagination'),
                    $itemContainer: base.Modal.Suggestion.$self.find('.request_items'),
                    $itemClone: base.Modal.Suggestion.$itemContainer.find('[data-id="Clonable"]').clone().removeAttr('data-id').removeClass('hide'),
                    $lblCount: base.Modal.Suggestion.$self.find('[data-id="SuggestCount"]'),
                    $listItems: function () {
                        return base.Modal.Suggestion.$itemContainer.find('.coll_panel_content:not([data-id="Clonable"])');
                    }
                }
            }
        };
});
```

I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$wrapper' of undefined` when you look at Google Chrome console.

[Some fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MyNameIsCode/DuFLd/1/)

I tried pulling out the `$wrapper` and now I get new error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Modal' of undefined
```

[Another fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/MyNameIsCode/XX4Zh/)

I made this approach because it is more easy to manage. For example, if I have changed some class name or id on my html page, I just have to modify 1 specific variable in my jquery code and everything will be fine again. If you know a better approach, kindly share it to me.

Comment: Because you can't access the object nor its properties upon its creation. Try another approach, like closures, constructors or something.

Comment: All the references to `base.XXX` fail because the `base` variable hasn't been assigned yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the variable you're defining while you're defining it. So a shorter example would be:

```
var hi = "hi" + hi.length;
```

Because the variable isn't completely defined yet.

To make your code work, define the variables you need beforehand:

```
$(function(){
    var $wrapper = $('.homepage_main'),
        $modalSelf = $('#suggested_colleague'),
        $itemContainer = $modalSelf.find('.request_items');
    var base = {
            $main: $wrapper.find('#primary').find('.home_slides').closest('[data-id="Colleague"]'),
            $panel: $wrapper.find('#sidebar').find('.home_slides').closest('[data-id="Colleague"]'),

            Template: {
                $img: function () { return $('img'); }
            },

            Modal: {
                $modalInterrupt: $('#searching_interruption'),
                Suggestion: {
                    $loading: $modalSelf.find('.gif_loading'),
                    $paging: $modalSelf.find('.pagination'),
                    $itemClone: $itemContainer.find('[data-id="Clonable"]').clone().removeAttr('data-id').removeClass('hide'),
                    $lblCount: $modalSelf.find('[data-id="SuggestCount"]'),
                    $listItems: function () {
                        return $itemContainer.find('.coll_panel_content:not([data-id="Clonable"])');
                    }
                }
            }
        };
});
```